# Backup MySQL Database without blob data

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup, blob

Situation:
I have a MySQL database that I would like to backup/export as an sql file.
The database has a single table in it that contains a longblob field.
I want to export the database without the data/contents of the longblob field.

Problem:
Not sure how to export the database without the longblog field's data.

Desired result:
A shell/php script or command that will create a sql file containing that database backup without the contents of the longblog field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip objects by type, use the --skip option with a list of the objects to skip. This enables you to extract a particular set of objects, say, for exporting only events (by excluding all other types). Similarly, to skip creation of UPDATE statements for BLOB data, specify the --skip-blobs option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbexport.html